# Embedding a podcast player onto my Craft site

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm pasting the embed code below into the HTML section but the player is not appearing. I do not have access to templates on my site. Is there a quick fix to get this to work?

I tried adding a plug in but can't work out how I do that.

Answer (score 1):

Not having access to the templates could make this hard to troubleshoot. Are you pasting into the HTML editor of a Redactor field? If so try editing the field's advanced options. Uncheck Remove inline styles, Remove empty tags, and Purify HTML.